# Trying to get a group count per 15 minutes

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

In a old database a date column is stored as 12-10-2012 15:20:36. I need to know the usage in a timeframe of 15 minutes. I grabbed parts of information from here but this script below gives me zero results. What do I miss?

```
$stats = mysql_query("SELECT
    count(id) as count,
    CASE 
        WHEN minute(STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s')) BETWEEN 0 and 14 THEN '00'
        WHEN minute(STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s')) BETWEEN 15 and 29 THEN '15'
        WHEN minute(STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s')) BETWEEN 30 and 44 THEN '30'
        WHEN minute(STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s')) BETWEEN 45 and 59 THEN '45'
    END AS intervals
FROM errors
GROUP BY intervals");
while($stat = mysql_fetch_object($stats)) {
    echo $stat->intervals." - ".$stat->count."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Have you ran `select STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s') from errors`  , and does the output look sensible ?

Comment: Uhm, just did, not at all, i only get white space...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s` instead of `%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s`. `%H` will accept 0-23 as value for hour.

`SELECT STR_TO_DATE( '12-10-2012 15:20:36', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s' )` will return `12-10-2012 15:20:36`

`SELECT STR_TO_DATE( '12-10-2012 15:20:36', '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s' )` will return `NULL`

Sometimes size matters :)

Comment: Argh... costs me a hour, I overlooked it... well, it's running now, thanks!